# How to get the start and end time to full calendar

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I need to get the start time and the end time of the even I have saved in the database,

I was able to get the start date and end date from the `start_date` & `end_date` fields from the database and display it in the full calendar as shown in the below image

[image]

But I need to get the times too from the database from the fields `start_time` & `end_time`

Here's how my database fields looks like

[image]

I just need to know how can I display the time range as the date range here

[image]

Here's my scripts

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dashbord-body").removeClass("bg-white");
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            selectable:true,
            height:650,
            showNonCurrentDates:false,
            editable:false,
            defaultView:'month',
            yearColumns: 3,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next', //note no "buttons
                center: 'title',
                right: 'year,agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,timelineCustom'
              
            },

            eventSources: [
            {
            url: '/calendar', // use the `url` property
            color: 'red',    // an option!
            textColor: 'white',  // an option!
            }

            ],
              eventDataTransform: function(eventData) {
                    return {
                        title: eventData.name,
                        start: eventData.start_date,
                        end: eventData.end_date
                    }
                },

        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Controller function

```
 public function calendar()
{
   
    $calendar= Event::latest()->get();

    return response()->json($calendar);
}
```

Comment: For fullCalendar to be able to take account of your time data you need to combine the date and time into a single "start" field and a single "end" field before you send it back to fullCalendar. You can do that in the server function or in eventDataTransform. I'm not sure why you're storing them separately in the database to begin with though anyway. that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @ADyson you mean, i need to combine `start_date` and `start_time` together in the controller function and pass it as `start` in the json response to the full calendar ?

Comment: Yes. Or you can do it in eventDataTransform if you prefer. It doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue I faced here by below codes in my controller function

```
public function calendar(Job $job)
{
$user = auth()->user();

$calendar = $job->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();

$calendar = $calendar->map(function ($post) {
    $post['start'] =  $post->start_date . ' ' . $post->start_time;
    $post['end'] =  $post->end_date . ' ' . $post->end_time;
    // unset($post['name']);
    return $post;
});

return response()->json($calendar);
}
```

And added the extra field name to the Model as below code

```
protected $visible  = ['start','end'];
```